# What happens if I accidentally delete the contents of /etc/pam.d/password-auth

Tags: linux, pam

Situation: Poking around some system files in `/etc/`

Problem: I managed to accidentally `rm`-ed some files, including `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (don't ask...)

Question: What are the ramifications (if any) of removing such files? I dare not log out or reboot for now.

Additional information: Machine is running CentOS 7. Will also be interested to know ramifications on top of just replacing the files.

Comment: Don't log out. Don't reboot. Please [tell us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/616578/edit) exactly what version of Unix or the distribution of Linux you're using, so someone can tell you where/how to get those files back

Comment: @roaima updated my question. It's CentOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've still got root, this will restore the two files you've named

```
cd /etc/pam.d
ln -s password-auth-ac password-auth
ln -s system-auth-ac system-auth
```

Test by using a new session to login with `ssh`. (If necessary, `ssh localhost` from the machine itself.) If the login succeeds then you've fixed it - without these files you cannot authenticate or authorise any session for any work. (In the `/etc/pam.d` directory you can `grep -l system-auth *` and `grep -l password-auth *` to see which services were affected. It makes for unpleasant reading.)